# How to configure MySQL 8.0.21 to use databases from 8.0.18 on macOS 10.14

Tags: macos, upgrade, mysql-8.0

I upgraded MYSQL 8.0.18 to 8.0.21, on my Mac Mojave, using the release mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64, which Oracle says supports Mojave 10.14...

Now I can't get MySQL to access the databases created under the previous version. I've tried all that I could find:

stop mysql server

a) copying (cp -aR ) the /usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/data directory to mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64. Start server. Results in the mysql server NOT starting... (yes, permissions, ownership, and structure are exactly what they need to be).

or

b) selectively copying (cp -aR) only the database directories and ibdata1 file from ...old../data across to ...new../data . Start server. MySQL starts, but my "old" databases are not available.

Any help with this would be appreciated. I 'm stuck. I believe this is possible, I perhaps need to copy just the *right files* over to the new directory...

Comment: Is there only one folder named mysql in /usr/local/? In my case two directory and service data file at /usr/local/mysql/data/.  Have you verified result of "ps aux|grep mysql" .. also need to verify same user & group pair in "/etc/passwd".

Comment: Regrettably, I found no way to resolve this according to "common" knowledge (migrating the data directory). So, I used "time machine" (mac's backup/ restore utility), restored my mysql 8.0.18 installation, then dumped my databases, then reinstalled 8.0.21 and then restored my databases. Caution to others: in the world of mysql 8+ there is no downgrade available, nor is there, it seems, an intelligent upgrade. It is all brute force: backup your dbs, install new product, restore your dbs...

Comment: I wish it was as easy as it is on AWS RDS (running MySQL). Select the version you want to upgrade to and click upgrade now... then, magic happens: Minutes later new DB is operating... I guess we get what we pay for... :)